# Pandas: filter large (50M rows) dataframe if row lat/lng falls inside a bounding box?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set that I'm evaluating various means of parsing on. It's a set of csv with each file having ~40 million rows. Reading into a pandas dataframe I have the following sample data. (The data that follows was randomly generated) The account identifiers will repeat from time to time, some in the box, some out. I have this working in a 'brute force' manner using csv readers and have gotten the processing time down to ~ 60 seconds for a randomly generated 10 million row sample. I'm hoping I can get it more efficient with pandas, because the real data set is much much larger, and we may need to do this kind of parsing repeatedly in the future.

```
                            account        lat         lng  
0  f413e6cd-bbfe-463b-bf58-cba1a74a4aff    50.847615     70.826473  
1  8b2ceb89-7ce0-4e14-a5f0-28acb7b05d8b    18.545991     115.078981    
2  a51ab728-14b5-473c-bed1-91953da8ba22    30.699439     9.660661  
3  83e3964f-130f-49bc-9c4b-d46d4b48c2cb    7.906903      70.507260
4  84c75e57-5a5f-4314-80be-d1271ecd76ef    -20.325371    48.310855
```

This block describes the function by which I want to match the rows of the dataframe. I have multiple bounding boxes that I need to check for membership.

```
top = 49.3457868  # north lat
left = -124.7844079  # west long
right = -66.9513812  # east long
bottom = 24.7433195  # south lat

def in_bounds(lat, lng):
    if bottom <= lat <= top and left <= lng <= right:
        return True
    elif bottom2 <= lat <= top2 and left2 <= lng <= right2:
        return True
    else return False
```

I don't really understand how to apply a lambda function to all rows, while collecting the rows that match in a new dataframe, using criteria from multiple columns of the dataframe. I can't find any examples online that come close to this.

What I've got working so far looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DATA.csv')
df.columns = ['account', 'lat', 'lng']
accounts= df[(bottom <= df.lat) & (df.lat <= top) & (left <= df.lng) & (df.lng <= right)]

results = df[df.account.isin(accounts)]
results.to_csv('pd_out.csv', header=False, )
```

But that only applies a single bounding box. I can't figure out how to do the similar filtering as above, but using my in_bounds function. So how can I best do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff here, various lats and longs and some global variables, and ...  hard to follow it all.

Comment: @StephenRauch yah sorry, its more elegantly arranged in my real work, but was trying to boil it down to just the issue with Pandas that I couldn't solve. I'm sure that this is just some trick of pandas that isn't well documented. The stuff I'm using here is just a 'toy script' to work on mock data.

Comment: if @tai  did not solve your problem, then suggest you study the MCVE link and construct same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too beautiful, but to combine both conditions, you can use the `|` operator. Note the parenthesis around both box conditions.

```
box1_cond = (bottom <= df.lat) & (df.lat <= top) & (left <= df.lng) & (df.lng <= right)
box2_cond = (bottom2 <= df.lat) & (df.lat <= top2) & (left2 <= df.lng) & (df.lng <= right2)
accounts = df[box1_cond | box2_cond]
```

Comment: Ah ha. That does at least help. I had not found that sort of syntax example in the documentation. 
What if the conditions were dynamic though? ie, read in from a file?

Comment: @ZachSwanson I don't know about that. I think you should take a look at `read_csv` function

Comment: @ZachSwanson one thing that I can think of is [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) this function. If you store your data in SQL database, you can filter out data while reading.

Comment: sorry regarding the other question I asked, I was unclear. I'm good on reading the data in from file. What I was wondering is how I'd build a query similar to your answer, if the list of conditions was of unknown size (ie, the bounding boxes might be defined in a file). I think I see how I can do it by building a .query() on the dataframe, and build up the query iteratively, just not sure that's optimal. 

Anyways appreciate the answer, this gets the ball moving for me!

Comment: @ZachSwanson You can put it together if you want. Or do it step by step? Build the initial df first and do a query on the filtered df.